# ¿Por qué repite el mismo monto sumado para todas las filtas en mi consulta sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo mis columanas ya consultadas y mostrando:

```
Pais,
Estado
cantidad,
Retirado
Efectivos
```

En la columna `Costo` hago una subconsulta para saber la suma de cada `Estado`, la sub consulta por sí sola ya funciona y la probé por separado, pero al momento de implementar me suma de un `estado` y me las muestra en todos el mismo monto.

```
declare
@anho  int
select 
@anho = 2017;


select 

(select x.nom from BD.dbo.Ent x where x.IdEnt = ch.CodEnt) as Pais,
(select x.Nombre from BD.dbo.Co x where x.IdCo = ch.CodCo ) as Estado,
(select  COUNT(*) as total from BD.dbo.Mat x where x.IdC = ch.Cod) as cantidad,
(select  COUNT(*) as total from BD.dbo.Mat x where x.IdC = ch.Cod and FechaRetiro is not null) as Retirados,
(select  COUNT(*) as total from BD.dbo.Mat x where x.IdC = ch.Cod and FechaRetiro is null) as Efectivos,

Costo = isnull( (

(SELECT SUM(cc.valor) 
            FROM 
            Cuenta cc 
            inner join BD.dbo.Co c on cc.IdCo = c.IdC
            inner join BD.dbo.Mat xm on  xm.Cod = cc.IdA

                and xm.FechaRetiro is null 
                and cc.Gestion = @anho 
                and xm.Gestion = @anho
        where
        cc.IdS  = 24)
),0)

from Cuenta cc, BD.dbo.CargaH ch

group by ch.Gestion,
        ch.CodC,
        ch.Cod
```

Comment: Necesitaríamos ver algunos datos de ejemplo, el resultado esperado por tí, y el resultado que estás obteniendo. También la versión de SQL Server que estás usando

Comment: Te vendría muy bien aprender a usar [JOINS](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). Por otro lado, tu consulta te muestra todos los **Costo**  iguales porque tu subconsulta tiene un filtro fijo (cc.IdS = 24).
Saludos.

Answer (score 4):

Relaciona las dos tablas **Cuenta cc** y **BD.dbo.CargaH ch** de lo contrario tendrás un producto cartesiano de todos los registros de cc con todos los de ch; busca qué campos utilizar para unir estas dos entidades.

Saca las tablas **BD.dbo.Ent**, **BD.dbo.Co** y **BD.dbo.Mat** e implementalas relacionándolas igualmente dentro de la parte de inner join de la consulta por los mismos campos que utilizas en las dos primeras lineas de la selección y en la obtención del campo Costo.

Retoca después la agrupación e incluye los campos que usas `x.nom` y `x.Nombre`.

Debería quedarte algo así:

```
select C.nom, C.Nombre, count(C.*) as Cantidad, sum(C.Efectivos) as Efectivos, sum(C.Retirados) as Retirados, C.valor as Costo 
from 
(
select
x.nom, x.Nombre, sum(isnull(cc.valor,0)) as valor case(isnull(¿.FechaRetiro,0) = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as Efectivos,
case(isnull(¿.FechaRetiro,0) <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) as Retirados
from 
Cuenta cc inner join BD.dbo.Co c on cc.IdCo = c.IdC inner join BD.dbo.Mat xm on xm.Cod = cc.IdA inner join BD.dbo.CargaH ch on x.IdC = ch.Cod inner join BD.dbo.Ent x on x.IdEnt = ch.CodEnt where cc.Gestion = @anho and xm.Gestion = @anho and cc.IdS = 24
group by x.nom, x.Nombre, FechaRetiro ) C
group by C.nom, C.Nombre, C.valor
```